# Alternate log location for commands in crontab

Tags: ubuntu, logging, cron

When we add  `* * * * * myTask.sh 2>&1 >> /var/log/myTask.log` to the crontab, all logs are entered to `myTask.log` However, I want to know if there is any way we can provide an alternate location (even if it is `/dev/null`) so that if due to some reason the location is inaccessible (due to deletion or permissions) the job should not get affected.

Please let me know if there is anyway we can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to use `sponge` from the `moreutils` package.  That is, `sudo apt-get install moreutils`, then:

```
* * * * * myTask.sh 2>&1 | sponge /var/log/myTask.log
```

The program sponge absorbs all its input, then only writes it at the end.  This means the file won't be checked for permissions or anything else until your program has finished.  On the downside, sponge will consume as much memory as it needs to buffer its input, so if your program prints a lot, this could be undesirable.

Comment: `myTask.sh` is actually a server start command. So there will be a lot of logs.

Comment: A lot like 40 MB, or a lot like 40 GB?

Comment: Depends. It may go to hundreds of MBs. Isn't there any other opt ?

Comment: The other option I have in mind would be to write a script to do whatever you want.  But you'll need to be somewhat careful if you want this to be super-robust--think about what happens if the output file is initially writable but later not (e.g. disk full).  You could do this in almost any language if you're careful.

Comment: Ok. Just want to know if the log location is inaccessible, does it affect the job ?

Comment: In your original code, yes it will affect the job.  It will likely crash it.